# ToArray() in C# changing the order of the items in the list

Tags: c#

I am saving a set of data in the Database. FOr ex:

Data on the database

```
ID  name     value
0   param1    1
0   param2    2
0   param3    3
0   param4    4
0   param5    5
0   param6    6
0   param7    7
0   param8    8
1   param1    1
1   param2    2
0   param9    9
0   param10    10
1   param3    3
1   param4    4
```

I query for selecting the rows with ID == 0, I get 10 data set rows in response. List myCollection is created and updated after looping through rows.
The expected list would be

```
param1
param2
param3
param4
param5
param6
param7
param8
param9
param10
```

After that to update one more structure, I am doing myCollection.ToArray()
But I am getting

```
param9
param10
param1
param2
param3
param4
param5
param6
param7
param8
```

I dont know where the problem is happening. Since I am not able reproduce the issue.  I have added instrumentation for now. ANy help would be great to know where the problem is happening whether in the data retrieval from database or in ToArray()

Thanks

Comment: If you want the result as ordered, then you can use `OrderBy` method. `ToArray()` is not sufficienet for the desired result. It will return rows in the order, that database returned as a result.

Comment: are you sure that it's not the DB that does the sorting?

Comment: Without the code it's kinda hard to tell...

Comment: Bearing in mind that data in relational databases (usually safe to assume without any evidence to the contrary in the question) has *no* inherent ordering. The only way to get data out of a database in a particular order is to specify an `ORDER BY` clause - one with enough specificity such that the order is uniquely defined. Are you using such an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: string sql = @"SELECT  ID, name, 
                                   value
                           FROM    TABLEREQUEST
                           WHERE   ID = @Id";

Comment: @user1097482 that query doesn't guarantee any particular order - the RDBMS can return those rows in *any order it likes*. If you want it in a specific order: add an `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL. Note that in the case of an unordered SQL query, the order it *actually* comes back in can depend on any number of factors, including ambient server load (which can impact whether the server decides to parallelize, etc)

Comment: @user1097482 note: the interesting next questions is: what are you going to order it *by*; you can't order by `name`, because that will give you `param1`, `param10`, `param2`. If it was me, I would have added an `order` or `sequence` column (`int not null`) that I use for the `order by`. If you always insert in ascending order and never change the names, I guess you could order by the `identity` column (assuming you have one)

Comment: I am not using ORDER BY clause. I am just executing the command mentioned below:

Comment: Is there any document, where I can row find the factory affecting returning of the rows for RDBMS

Comment: @ Marc Gravell - Thank you for the suggestion. Right now I am not using ORDER By since I dont have any column value on which I can perform the command. As you mentioned I need to add one more column, i.e., sequence column and use it for order by. But I also wanted to know where is it being documented that the oder of the item during retrieval of data from RDBMS depends on. Can you please share the link if you have one.

Comment: It *isn't* documented since there are so many variations that are possible. From upgrades, service packs and patches, through resource usage, indexes and statistics, and even as far as what other queries are/were running. That's why you'll find people telling you repeatedly that the only way to *know* what order you'll get data back from the database is to add an `ORDER BY` clause that tells the server what guarantees *you* need for your particular query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well, actually it *is* documented - as being explicitly non-deterministic ;p [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) "The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified."

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Thanks a lot. I have changed code to get the rows using ORDER By clause

Answer (score 3):

> `ToArray()` in C# changing the order of the items in the list

No, it isn't. Either:

- the data hasn't been fetched in a defined order in the first place (in the case of SQL, you should add an `ORDER BY`), or
- it has been stored in an intermediate object that *does not preserve order*, for example a `HashSet<>` or a `Dictionary<,>`

Without more code, we can't diagnose. But: without doubt, it isn't `ToArray()` that is doing this.